# Sending metta to fictional charcters ?

Tags: metta

Is there a point sending metta to fictional characters like in a movie or a computer game ?

Comment: Buddhism, practicing the dharma, or even only thinking about it (seriously), is not a game of putting together words. "A game" is what comes up in my mind when I only read your sentence. (-1) Any serious approach to get familiar to that what was the concern of the Buddha would easily have detected that the concern of the Buddha was the living people.

Answer (score 5):

It could actually be unskillful as you are strengthening your ignorance to think that such characters are real.

Answer (score 3):

Metta is practitioner's consciousness that thinking to **make happy consciousness** arise in **the other lives**. (sukhī attānaṃ pariharantu)

Fictional charcters never have happy **consciousness arising**.

Answer (score 0):

If anger arises while you watching a movie or playing a computer game, it is a good idea that you are aware of your mental state.